# How to bypass 1st set of conditionals

Tags: python

its my second day of class in introductory programming and im having trouble. We are on if statements. The homework is

Write a program that prompts the user for an integer (you can assume that the
value entered will be an integer). If that integer is equal to zero, print “zero”. If not, determine if
it is positive or negative and print which one it is. Also, determine if the number is evenly divisible
by 5 or not.

Now i can prompt the user for a number and determine if its positve or negative or if its divisible by 5 but i dont know how to make the program bypass the unmet first condition and go into the second set of condition, example of my code below,

```
number = input("enter an integer: ")

if number > 0 and number%5 == 0:
    print number, "is positive and divisible by 5"
else :
    print "positive but not divisible by 5"

if number < 0 and number%5== 0:
    print "neggy and divisible by 5"
else :
    print "neggy but not divisible by 5"
```

my problem is that when i type a negative number it print "positive but not divisible by 5" because the 1st condition wasnt met. I tried elif but i get a syntax error averytime, help?
Please dont go to fancy as my teacher only wants the basic "and", "or", "if", "else", and "elif", words used. Thanks

Comment: Does 0 count as divisible by 5?

Answer (score 6):

Use elif:

```
number = input("enter an integer: ")

if number > 0 and number%5 == 0:
    print number, "is positive and divisible by 5"
elif number > 0:
    print "positive but not divisible by 5"
elif number < 0 and number%5== 0:
    print "neggy and divisible by 5"
elif number < 0:
    print "neggy but not divisible by 5"
else:
    print "zero"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use `if ... elif ... else` but anyway, I'm throwing another option in:

```
if number == 0:
    print 'zero'
else:
    print number, 'is', 'positive' if number > 0 else 'negative', 'and',
    print 'not' if number % 5 else '', 'divisible by 5'
```

Explanation... This takes advantage of the way the `print` statement in Python 2 can take several values separated by commas, and displays the values separated by spaces; and it uses [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), which allow you to rewrite (e.g.)

```
if condition:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

as

```
print 'yes' if condition else 'no'
```

but are not very highly recommended because they often make code less readable.

Comment: I personally really like the trinary, but for the sake of argument, you should probably expound on exactly how this works in this case; because there's quite a bit around the trinary going on.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s tackle each of the tests separately first. So first of all, you want to check if it is positive or negative (or zero even). That is one “category” of properties, because a number cannot be both positive and negative:

```
if number > 0:
    # number is positive
elif number < 0:
    # number is negative
else:
    # number is zero
```

Of course, you can order those checks however you want; you could also check for zero first etc.

So, the second check if it is divisible by 5 or not. That’s a second category, so we have to handle that separately from the sign:

```
if number % 5 == 0:
    # number is divisible by 5
else:
    # number is not divisible by 5
```

So now we have two *separate* checks for two *separate* property categories. If we want a single output for both properties (e.g. *“positive and divisible by 5”* as you already used in your code). There are different ways to interlock those two checks now. One would be to simply put one into the other one, like this:

```
if number > 0:
    if number % 5 == 0:
        print('Number is positive and divisible by 5')
    else:
        print('Number is positive but not divisible by 5')
elif number < 0:
    if number % 5 == 0:
        print('Number is negative and divisible by 5')
    else:
        print('Number is negative but not divisible by 5')
else:
    print('Number is zero')
```

As you can see, this is just the second check pasted into each of the (appropriate) cases of the first check. Note that this will unnecessarily increase the indentation level, so we might want to look how we can avoid that.

You already started with this in your code, we basically want to combine two checks using `and`. Note that we need to make sure that in the above solution, the *inner* else cases (from the divisibility) still expects the outer (sign check) to be true. So we need to make sure that we keep that:

```
if number > 0 and number % 5 == 0:
    print('Number is positive and divisible by 5')
elif number > 0:
    print('Number is positive but not divisible by 5')
elif number < 0 and number % 5 == 0:
    print('Number is negative and divisible by 5')
elif number < 0:
    print('Number is negative but not divisible by 5')
else:
    print('Number is zero')
```

As you can see, we’re down to a single indentation level, and we have all our checks within a single if-elif-else structure. This unfortunately forces us to have some duplication in the checks as explained above. That’s because when checking for two things in a single if, we don’t know which is false when we get to the else/elif. So if we still want to make sure that e.g. the number is positive when it wasn’t positive *and* divisible by 5, we have to check for that again.

This is essentially what you forgot: Your else could actually only say *“not positive or not divisible by 5”*.

Now, to take this just *a bit* further, we can actually still get rid of the duplication. Because our two “property categories” are completely independent, we can check them independently (just like we did at the beginning). To get a combined output, all we need to do is to construct that output sequentially:

```
# because zero is a special case, we handle it separately
# while sacrificing an indentation level.
if number == 0:
     print('Number if zero')
else:
    # check for the sign first
    if number > 0:
        output = 'Number is positive'
    else:
        output = 'Number is negative'

    # check for the divisibility next
    if number % 5 == 0:
        output += ' and divisibile by 5'
    else:
        output += ' but not divisible by 5'

    # whatever the checks resulted in, we have our output
    print(output)
```

Of course this might be a bit too far for your task yet, but it might be good to know for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if number == 0:
    print "zero"
else:

    pos = (number > 0 )
    div_by_5 = (number % 5 == 0)

    if pos and div_by_5:
        print number, "is positive and div by 5"
    elif pos and not div_by_5:
        print number, "is positive but not div by 5"
    elif not pos and div_by_5:
        print number, "is negative and div by 5"
    elif not pos and not div_by_5:
        print number, "is negative but not div by 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7.4

```
number = int(raw_input())

if not number: print "zero"
elif abs(number) % 5 == 0:
    print [ `number` + " is negative and divisible by 5", 
        `number` + " is positive and divisible by 5"][number > 0]
else: print [ `number` + " is negative but not divisible by 5", 
        `number` + " is positive but not divisible by 5"][number > 0]
```

[Backtick](http://www.littletechtips.com/2009/11/python-backticks.html)

Comment: Backticks were removed in Python 3, so it’s not a good idea to advertise for them. Also using list indexing is a rather confusing way to do this, definitely not recommended for beginners (and doesn’t give you any benefits anyway). Finally `not number` for zero check: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: I know backticks were removed in python 3; Which is why I specified the python version I was using. I provided a solution that is different from all the other ones that were submitted. My solution does the same thing as all the others albeit a bit awkward to read. I know this and this is why I submitted it. Sometimes it is nice to have variety